# cache coherence - Why are some steps considered exclusive?

Tags: caching, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache, cpu-cores, mesi

Given this prelude:

> consider a system with 2 cores, P1 and P2 using write back and write
> allocate schemes.
>
> the addresses A1 and A2 are mapped to  the same cache block but A1 IS
> not equal A2. Initial cache is invalid. Use the MESI protocol here.
>
> The following steps are taken:
>
> 1. P1 writes the value 10 to A1
> 2. P1 reads the value at A1
> 3. P2 reads the value at A1
> 4. P2 writes the value of 20 to A1
> 5. P2 writes the value of 40 to A2
> 6. P1 reads the value at A1

I'm wondering, in step 1 why is that action of P1 writing to A1 considered as 'exclusive'? I would've thought that it would be 'modified' considering that we are writing to the address?

This example is taken from this source [http://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~pattrsn/252F96/Lecture18.pdf](http://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Epattrsn/252F96/Lecture18.pdf)

Here is the end state table: [image: cache table]

Could someone explain why Steps 1 and 4 are considered "exclusive" and not modified?

Comment: Yeah, I'd expect Modified when P1 writes to A1.  Maybe they're just lumping Modified in with Exclusive, since Modified does still imply exclusive ownership.

Comment: @PeterCordes ok thank you! never considered that modified would be lumped together with exclusive~ thanks for bringing that up :)

Comment: I mean, it's possible, but it still seems like a mistake, especially in formal terminology when the assignment specifically said MESI, not MSI.  (And write-back cache, so it definitely needs to support being dirty or not.)

Comment: It's not MESI that is being used though, it's "Basic Protocol" defined in slides 19-22. There is no M state in the basic protocol.

Comment: @HadiBrais Oh! thanks for spotting that! Missed that completely, I assumed it was MESI. So if it was MESI then it would be like what Peter mentioned and the state would be Modified when P1 writes to A1